# jQuery mobile - get the loaded page ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a document called "info.html".

it have 5 pages:

1. food
2. toys
3. entertainment
4. smartphones
5. electronics

I want that once a page loads, jquery send a request to the server for information about this item.

I all need to know is how to trigger this function?

Tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>CoCouppn!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).on("pageshow", function() {
                alert($(this).attr('id'));
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" class="pge" id="food">
            food
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" class="pge" id="toys">
            toys
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" class="pge" id="entertainment">
            entertainment
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" class="pge" id="smartphones">
            smartphones
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" clsas="pge" id="electronics">
            electronics
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

It alerts "undifined" instead of page ID.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `pagechange` event and retrieve page's id from `data` object.

   ```
   $(document).on("pagechange", function (e, data) {
     var page = data.toPage[0].id;
   });
   ```

   > **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/sBLP6/)**
2. `pageshow`:

   ```
   $(document).on("pageshow", function (e, data) {
     var page = $(this)[0].activeElement.id;
   });
   ```

   > **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/EBt4V/)**

Answer (score 8):

Note that pageshow is deprecated in jQuery Mobile 1.4: http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/

Note also that $.mobile.activePage is deprecated.

If you want to get the active page ID, you can do:

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer( 'getActivePage' ).attr( 'id' );
```

or

```
$('body').pagecontainer( 'getActivePage' ).attr( 'id' );
```

or

```
$(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer( 'getActivePage' ).attr( 'id' );
```

I do not personally recommend the latter two, as you are free to set a different pagecontainer, which in fact I do in Jasmine tests.

Note that the page must really be active first (it is not active yet in pagecreate, for instance).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current page information in a shorter and clearer way:

```
$(".ui-page-active").attr("id")
```

This is just a variation from the code shown here: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/toolbar-fixed-persistent/#&ui-state=dialog

Answer (score -1):

Try `$(document).ready( function )`, $(document).ready allows you to execute a code in jQuery only when the page is loaded.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use `pagecreate` event, use `this.id`

```
$(document).on(
        "pagecreate",
        '#page_1, #page_2',
        function(event) {

            var pageId = this.id;
            ...
        }
```

);